# "Headers were already written" error when connecting to Golang API with go-socket.io and gin

Tags: go, sockets, socket.io, go-gin

I have an API project in Golang using the [socket.io](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) package and gin. The project is running in a live environment. When I send requests to the server using Postman, I can establish a socket connection successfully. However, when I try to connect through a JavaScript client on the web, I encounter an error. The error message I'm receiving is as follows: "Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 403 with 502."

Could anyone help me understand the cause of this error? Here's some additional information:

- The error occurs only when connecting via a JavaScript client on the web. Postman requests work fine.
- The server-side code uses the go-socket.io package for socket connections, along with gin for the API routes.
- I'm not sure which part of the code is causing the issue or if there's a conflict between gin and go-socket.io.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!